# Sentry is asking for Certificate on Rails Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, sentry

Im using rails 5 with sentry installed, I have tested it locally and it already works, however moving to production I am getting a certificate error when I boot up console and test  `Sentry.capture_message("new test 2")` with the following error:

```
Event sending failed: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (certificate has expired)
Unreported Event: new test 2
exception happened in background worker: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (certificate has expired)
```

My code is as follows

```
Sentry.init do |config|
  config.dsn = ENV["SENTRY_DNS"]
  config.breadcrumbs_logger = [:active_support_logger, :http_logger]
  config.traces_sample_rate = 0.25
  config.enabled_environments = %[ staging ]
end
```

Comment: Use `ENV.fetch("SENTRY_DNS")` instead. This will raise an error if the ENV var is not set and will save you tons of debugging time - do this any time you have a configuration setting that should not be allowed to be nil.

Comment: thanks for the tip, though I've tried hardcoding it and i still get the same error so something is still a miss

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your server is attempting to verify the ssl cert when connecting to sentry.  For

```
Sentry.init do |config|
  config.transport.ssl_verification = false
  config.dsn = ENV["SENTRY_DNS"]
  config.breadcrumbs_logger = [:active_support_logger, :http_logger]
  config.traces_sample_rate = 0.25
  config.enabled_environments = %[ staging ]
end
```

When attempting to send to sentry your server is failing to verify the SSL certificate correctly.  You can cancel verification by adding the above option.  This is a bit of a security hole so the more correct way would be to set:

```
config.transport.ssl_ca_file = 'path to a valid local cert file'
```

instead.